# playing songs with jplayer from mysql database using php and jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jplayer

I am developing a music streaming site and I am using jplayer to play songs on my site. I customized jplayer to better suit my site.
I created a database for my site and now want to play songs from database by using jplayer.
since I only know little about php and mysql, I can't figure it out how to do that? some how I am able to play a random song from a msql table with jplayer
but I want to generate links of each mp3 file and echoed them in an html lists so when get clicked loaded into jplayer and playing! simple is that!

```
getsong.php

 <?php

  if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){ 

include_once "ez_sql_core.php";
include_once "ez_sql_mysql.php";
$db = new ezSQL_mysql('root','','amr','localhost'); 

$song = $db->get_row("SELECT * FROM tracks ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

$artist = $song->album_id;
$songname = $song->name;
$track_url = $song->track_url;
$separator = '|';
echo $track_url.$separator.$artist.$separator.$songname;
} 

?>

jplayer-interface.php

 >     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
     var data = $.ajax({
      url: "../js/getsong.php",
       async: false
   }).responseText;
    var string = data.split('|');
  $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
    mp3: string[0]
  });          
  $('#artist').html(string[1]);
  $('#songname').html(string[2]);
},
ended: function (event) {  
  var data = $.ajax({
    url: "../js/getsong.php",
    async: false
   }).responseText;
    var string = data.split('|');
  $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
    mp3: string[0]
  });          
  $('#artist').html(string[1]);
  $('#songname').html(string[2]);
  },
swfPath: "../js/jPlayer",
supplied: "mp3, ogv, m4v, oga",
useStateClassSkin: true,
autoBlur: false,
smoothPlayBar: true,
keyEnabled: true,
audioFullScreen: false,
enableRemoveControls: false,
autoPlay: false,
loopOnPrevious: false,
shuffleOnLoop: true,
displayTime: 'slow',
addTime: 'fast',
removeTime: 'fast',
shuffleTime: 'slow'
 });
});
</script>
> 
> 
> 
>     <footer class="j-player">
 <div id="jp_container_1">
    <div class="jp-type-playlist">
        <div class="playlist_items jp-playlist"><!--start jp-playlist-->
            <ul>
                <!-- The method Playlist.displayPlaylist() uses this 
 unordered list -->
                <li>&nbsp;</li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--end jp-playlist-->
        <div class="lyrics-contents jp-lyrics"><!--start jp-lyrics-->
            <ul>
              <!-- The method Playlist.displayPlaylist() uses this unordered 
 list -->
              <li> </li>
            </ul><!--end jp-lyrics-->
        </div>
        <div id="jplayer_N" class="jp-jplayer hide"></div>
        <div class="jp-gui"> 
            <div class="jp-video-play hide">
                <a class="jp-video-play-icon">play</a>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-interface">
                <div class="jp-controls">
                    <div><div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer">
 </div> <!--@jquery_jplayer_1--></div>
                    <div class="previous-button"><a class="jp-previous"><i 
 class="arcd-controller-jump-to-start"></i></a></div>
                    <div class="play-button">
                        <a class="jp-play"><i class="flaticon-play62"></i>
 </a>
                        <a class="jp-pause hid"><i class="flaticon-pause35">
 </i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="next-button"><a class="jp-next"><i 
 class="arcd-controller-next"></i></a></div>
                    <div class="hide"><a class="jp-stop"><i class="fa fa-
 stop"></i></a></div>
                    <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                    <div class="jp-progress hidden-692">
                        <ul class="jp-details">
                            <li class="jp-title" id="songname" aria-
 label="title">&nbsp;</li>
                            <li class="jp-artist" id="artist" aria-
 label="artist">&nbsp;</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                            <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jp-duration"></div>
                    <div class="volume-speaker">
                        <a class="jp-mute" title="mute"><i class="arcd-
 music1432"></i></a>
                        <a class="jp-unmute hid" title="unmute"><i 
 class="arcd-mute10"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jp-volume">
                        <div class="jp-volume-bar vol-bar-bg">
                            <div class="jp-volume-bar-value vol-bar-seek">
 </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="shuffle-button">
                        <a class="jp-shuffle" title="shuffle"><i 
 class="arcd-shuffle shuffle-on"></i></a>
                        <a class="jp-shuffle-off hid" title="shuffle off"><i 
 class="arcd-shuffle shuffle-off"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="repeat-button">
                        <a class="jp-repeat" title="repeat"><i class="arcd-
 loop repeat-on"></i></a>
                        <a class="jp-repeat-off hid" title="repeat off"><i 
 class="arcd-loop repeat-off"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="playlist-button jp-toggles">
                        <a class="show-playlist" title="playlist-on"><i 
 class="arcd-lyrics1"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lyrics-button">
                        <a class="jp-show-lyrics" title="Lyrics"><i 
 class="arcd-note25"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hide">
                        <a class="jp-full-screen" title="full screen"><i 
 class="fa fa-expand"></i></a>
                        <a class="jp-restore-screen" title="restore screen">
 <i class="fa fa-compress"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/ .jp-controls1-->
            </div><!--/ .jp-interface-->
        </div><!--/ .jp-gui-->
        <div class="jp-no-solution hide">
            <span>Update Required</span>
            To play the media you will need to either update your browser to 
   a recent version or update your <a 
  href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" 
 target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
        </div>
    </div><!--/ .jp-type-playlist-->
  </div><!--/ .jp_container_1-->
 </footer>

 Any help will be really appreciated!
```

Comment: ezSQL_mysql uses the `mysql_*` functions, which have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). You should switch to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: "I want to generate links of each mp3 file and echoed them in an html lists so when get clicked loaded into jplayer and playing" Ok. And which part(s) of that are you having a problem with? You've obviously written quite a lot of code, but presumably something doesn't work? If so, please describe what goes wrong and what you want to know. You haven't actually asked us a question...